# Facebook Connect - Transferring the Session ID from WebView to the application back to the server

Tags: facebook, session, cookies, session-cookies

My application uses Facebook connect server-side login (using o-auth).
This means that the user gives power to the server to do action on his behalf.

Once the server received the TOKEN from Facebook, it set a "SESSIONID" attribute on the users request.

On the client side, I implemented this using a WebView, i.e. When the user opens the application for the first time, theres a webview with a facebook connect button, when it clicks on the button he will go to my server, get redirect to facebook and start the whole server-side login chain.

1. What is the best way to move the SESSION ID from the WebView, onto the other controllers?
2. Where is the best way to store it (Android/iPhone)
3. How should I append this SESSION ID on each request? Do i need to add a new header each time i send a request to my servers? (Since the session was set on the WebView "browser" and then is moved to the native client i assume the session is closed. correct?)